# Posting copyrighted material

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1532/how-was-this-equation-derived) includes a copy of a page from a copyrighted book. Credit is given to the original source, but there is no indication that the author has given permission for this use. Searching for this book on Google Books does not permit viewing the page concerned, suggesting that the copyright holder does not wish it to be shared online.

Where is the line between fair use and breaching copyright? Is a whole page too much to count as fair use?

Answer (score 5):

"Fair Use" is an exception to US Copyright Law that allows limited use of a copyrighted work in certain circumstances (in this case "teaching"). Without getting into all the nuances of Fair Use, the first factor of determining whether something is fair use is to consider if the new work is *transformative,* which simply means the new work must substantially build on and supersede the original work.

In other words, you cannot simply copy something and call it teaching. Since the post you linked above does ***not*** have any substantial content beyond simply showing what is in the book, this would not be considered fair use and would not be allowed.

I removed the post.

Comment: Wait, what? While this particular question was low quality and probably deserved to be closed or deleted, are you really saying that one can't post a *single page* from a book in order to ask a question about it? AFAIK, fair use is perfectly OK with quoting small portions of a work in order to comment on it or ask questions about it.

Comment: I'd be interested in your views on [this follow up meta question](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/207/is-there-an-exception-for-past-papers-or-does-this-question-need-to-be-deleted). The answer there links to two posts on Meta Stack Exchange that are from several years ago and I'm not clear on whether they still apply.