# Is there an exception for past papers or does this question need to be deleted?

Tags: discussion

[This meta question](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/posting-copyrighted-material) establishes that reproducing a work without building on it means that it does not qualify as fair use. The question mentioned at the time reproduced a page from a book without adding anything to it. As a result the question was deleted.

[This question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/how-to-determine-he-bandwidth-of-a-frame-store) reproduces a series of related questions from a past paper (the exact source is not specified).

Are basic exam questions covered by copyright law too? Does it depend on the country of origin of the exam paper? Is there anything to take into consideration or should reproduced exam questions be deleted on sight?

Answer (score 1):

Copyright is a very though cookie*. Laws differ significantly from country to country. Your expected to follow the law in your country no matter what the original author worked under. On top of that stackexchange needs to operate under US jurisdiction.

It is not our job to enforce copyright. You may want to read

- [dealing-with-posts-plagiarising-from-copyrighted-sources](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19508/dealing-with-posts-plagiarising-from-copyrighted-sources)
- [what-should-i-do-when-i-see-copyright-violations-posted-on-stack-overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114919/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-copyright-violations-posted-on-stack-overflow)

In essence the DCMA complaint is for this purpose. You can do whatever you like but you have no obligation to do anything about this matter. We do not even know if it is violating any copyright.

* for example code snippets on stackexchange rarely get copyright in my jurisdiction as they do not qualify as copyrightable works unless they are significant codebases (30 lines rarely is a significant codebase). On the other hand publishers have natural moral rights to whatever they write, so I will need to attribute that code no matter what the license of stackexchange says. If its copyrightable it may be copyrightable as a textual work in which case i can obtain a license form the appropriate local trade organization, on your behalf. After having done this you have no copyright claim I've handled my end. Unfortunately the trade organization does not have to pay you until your account has a significant sum of money or your a member.

But if I wan't to use my code in US i better follow the copyright holders wishes anyway. Which I do for moral reasons. If you want to know more about my local laws can try to google translate [this article](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/tekoik/all.html) but im afraid it wont work out very well.

**PS**: None of the exams ive ever made have any copyright protection per see. Which is why its standard that student unions keep databases of past exams where I am.

**DISCLAIMER** I am not a copyright lawyer and certainly not **your** copyright lawyer.